# Cant connect to wifi on 13.04

Tags: wireless

Just installed 13.04 but cant connect to home wifi using realtek 8188 wlan adapter it keeps asking for password.

Comment: You should enter the password..

Comment: please provide the lspci output ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the program asks your password, you can be sure that your wireless card is working. 
Check with

```
ip link
```

You should see eth1 (or wlan0) with 'state UP'

There are different solutions

- Reboot
- `sudo rfkill` your wireless card (disable an re-enable it)
- Power off your WIFI-router. Wait some time and restart.

I had the same problem when I upgraded to 13.04. 
I don't remember what solution I chose. Maybe all.